# What is Bertrand Russell citing Gilman for in "On the Notion of Order"?

Tags: mathematics

In the first few pages of "[On the Notion of Order](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2247671)", Bertrand Russell has the footnote:

> The following account of the genesis of order is virtually identical with that of Mr. B. I. Gilman, Mind, N. S., vol. i.

I thought just putting this into Google would suffice, but somehow I got lots of results that are far too recent to be attributed in something published *circa* 1901.

What work is Bertrand Russell actually citing here?

Answer (score 3):

In [*Mind*, N. S. Vol. $\rm I$](https://archive.org/details/nsmindrev01edinuoft/page/n5/mode/2up) (p. $519$), there is *[On The Properties of a One-Dimensional Manifold](https://academic.oup.com/mind/article-abstract/1/4/518/949782?redirectedFrom=fulltext)* by B. I. Gilman.

Russell was citing this work, if I am not wrong.